# Django - having more than one foreignkey in the same model

Tags: python, mysql, django, postgresql, pgadmin

models.py

```
class City(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    countrycode = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    population = models.IntegerField(default='0')

class Country(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=3)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=52)
    continent = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=26)
    surfacearea = models.FloatField()
    indepyear = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    population = models.IntegerField()
    lifeexpectancy = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    gnp = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    gnpold = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    localname = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    governmentform = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    headofstate = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    capital = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    code2 = models.CharField(max_length=2)
```

**SQL For the models**

*for City*
`INSERT INTO city VALUES (3955,'Sunnyvale','USA','California',131760);`

*for Country*
`INSERT INTO country VALUES ('BHS','Bahamas','North America','Caribbean',13878.00,1973,307000,71.1,3527.00,3347.00,'The Bahamas','Constitutional Monarchy','Elisabeth II',148,'BS');`

**Question 1**
In the above mentioned models how can i relate code in the `Country.code` to `City.countrycode`, i am not able to do so because Country model is declared after the City model.

**Question 2**
And how to link the `Country.capital in` the Country model which is a integer that relates to `City.name`.

**Note**
I am converting a `.sql` file with InnoDB Engine to Postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need declare [foreign key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) related by string

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    countrycode = models.ForeignKey('Country', blank=True, null=True)


class Country(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=3)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=52)
    capital = models.ForeignKey('Country', blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: I don't understand,  i get *city.countrycode_id does not exist* error

Comment: yes, i don't get how `id` column is automatically added to the table.